# Google Sheets consecutive rows when multiple checkboxes are ticked

Tags: google-sheets, checkbox

I am looking for help with this sheet. I have some item names and images next to those. They belong together.

Whenever I tick the first checkbox in the item sheet, I want the item name and the image to be displayed in Sheet 2. I have managed to do that with the formula in A1 for the image

`=Iferror(VLOOKUP(B1,Items!B4:F15,2,FALSE),"")`

and for the item name formula in B1 I used

`=iferror(QUERY(Items!B4:F15,"select B where D=True"),"")` .

My problem is:

When I tick the first checkbox of any item, the item gets normally displayed in Sheet2 with the belonging image. When I tick the second checkbox for that same item (x2), I want the same item to be displayed right again in the second row in Sheet2 with the belonging image again. If I tick the third checkbox, I want it to be displayed three times basically below each other with the belonging image.

Is that possible without scripts?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tjyBIMDWbM4AxuQby4vmEUeFgqLbxN1EPk1pGqEX_64/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
=sort(filter({
ifna(filter(Items!B4:C,Items!D4:D),{"",""});
ifna(filter(Items!B4:C,Items!E4:E),{"",""});
ifna(filter(Items!B4:C,Items!F4:F),{"",""})},query({
ifna(filter(Items!B4:C,Items!D4:D),{"",""});
ifna(filter(Items!B4:C,Items!E4:E),{"",""});
ifna(filter(Items!B4:C,Items!F4:F),{"",""})},"select Col1")<>""))
```

**UPDATE**: Better approach

```
=sortn({
ifna(filter(Items!A4:B,Items!D4:D),if({1,1},char(999)));
ifna(filter(Items!A4:B,Items!E4:E),if({1,1},char(999)));
ifna(filter(Items!A4:B,Items!F4:F),if({1,1},char(999)))},
countif(Items!D4:F,true),,2,1)
```

Essentially we are filtering the data three times (one for each checkbox), stacking all the results together and sorting them in ascending order. The `if({1,1},char(999))` is used as padding in case there's no match (i.e. no checkbox is ticked) to prevent ARRAY_LITERAL. The idea with `char(999)` is to have a character that goes to the bottom of the list when the range is sorted so we can exclude it with `sortn()`. I don't know how Google Sheets sorts when special characters are involved (if anyone does please let me know) but `char(999)` seems to get the job done.

Comment: Thank you, thats amazing. Do you mind to explain me this part of your formula?

```ifna(filter(Items!B4:C,Items!F4:F),{"",""})},query({
ifna(filter(Items!B4:C,Items!D4:D),{"",""});
ifna(filter(Items!B4:C,Items!E4:E),{"",""});
ifna(filter(Items!B4:C,Items!F4:F),{"",""})},"select Col1")<>""))```

Comment: Also, how can I get the image to the left of the text instead of right as it is now?

Comment: thank you so much, I will have to invest some time to fully understand your formula. I changed in your last line the D4:E to D4:F (I think thats what you wanted to write anyway) and now it looks perfect.

Comment: right. fixed it.

Comment: I have one last question: Right now the generated list with items is sorted A->Z when checkboxes are checked. Is it possible to sort the list by the order of addition of each checkbox?

Comment: I'm afraid that's not possible.